# jQuery Validate - Onsubmit dont leave the page and erase the inputdata in the fields

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, fancybox

I got a form that I submit and then Id like to have the data I just submitted show up in a iframe with the fancybox popup-plugin.

The form is validated via jQuery validate plugin from Jörn, and when I click the submit button the form checks if everything validates as it should, and it sends me to the other page because of the

I want to have the form submitted to another page that Ill show in a fancybox iframe box if that is possible. And still have the form in the background showing all the text-input in the fields as it was when it was submitted.

The problem I got is that I cannot connect the submitbutton to the fancybox plugin so it will show me the other page in an "iframe" popup with the confirmation page that shows all the data I submitted.

I tried to use this:

```
$(".confirmation").fancybox({

        'autoDimensions'    : true,
        'width'             : 800,
        'height'            : 300,
        'transitionIn'      : 'none',
        'transitionOut'     : 'none',
        'overlayColor'      : '#000000',
        'overlayOpacity'    : 0.8,
        'type'              : 'iframe'
});
```

I gave the submitbutton another ID:

```
<input type="submit" id="submit confirmation" name="submit" value="Send" href="/secpak/confirmation/" />
```

That didnt work either, tried a few other things but I still cant get it to work, any other guys in this world that got any ideas och tips and tricks to get this stuff to work?

Best Regards,

EIGHTYFO

Comment: you can't set multiple id's on an element and you do: $(".confirmation") the dot means a classname nog an id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're specifying invalid id (contains space). I guess you meant "class" attribute, not "id". also the jQuery selector suggests it was supposed to be class ;)

Comment: Thnx for the help, all stressed out and didnt see that :D